# SVN/Subclipse Expired SSL Certificate Error

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssl, subclipse

I use Eclipse/Subclipse to share my project with a SVN repo at, say, `https://svn.blah.example.com:443`.

Just this morning, I started getting the following error when I try to synchronize my local working copy with the repo:

```
Error validating server certificate for https://svn.blah.example.com:443:
    - Unknown certificate issuer
      Fingerprint: <I'm omitting the fingerprint for privacy reasons>
      Distinguished name: MySVNRepo, LLC
    - Certificate is expired
      Valid until Thu, 06 Jun 2013 21:22:13 GMT
```

Is this a problem with my local configuration (perhaps I have an expired certificate locally on my machine?) or is this something the admins hosting the repo will have to address, and why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *server* certificate has expired! :) I hope that they already know about the problem however it makes sense to notify them about this issue.

```
Valid until Thu, 06 Jun 2013 21:22:13 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks @bahrep (+1) - 2 followups: (1) can you please confirm that this is something they have to change on their end (and perhaps explain what needs to happen), and (2) I have a few co-workers who use the same project/repo and this is not happening for them. Any idea as to how/why this could be? I know Subclipse lets you use LDAP (as opposed to SSL) for certain authentication; so perhaps I'm configured for SSL and they are authenticating with pure LDAP?!?! Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja just show the error you get to a sysadmin, he should know how to process the case. BTW, I doubt that this is related to authentication.

Comment: Thanks again @bahrep (+1 again) - not trying to be difficult here, but I don't feel comfortable registering a complaint with the admin unless I'm 100% sure that this isn't an issue with my local configuration. Can you perhaps explain *why* this is something that the admin needs to fix (and not me)? Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, 'cause the error says "Certificate is expired Valid until **Thu, 06 Jun 2013 21:22:13 GMT**" This is the server certificate and your client does not trust it since it has expired yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, my reservation was that it was something misconfigured/expired on the **client-side** instead of the server. Thanks again.